# Sparse Connectivity in Keras CNNs

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I tried to implement the LeNet-5 architecture from LeCunns original paper. On page 8, the authors describe how which feature map from layer C3 are connected to which feauture maps from layer S2.

While I generally understand how to implement a CNN in Keras, I haven't found a way to implement this behaviour in the sequential API, since by default, all feature maps are connected to all feature maps from the layer below. Is there an easy way to implement the sparse connectivity or do you have to define your own custom layers?